# User ID required to send mail with Email.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

So I'm trying to implement this email function into my portfolio, I will insert current code at the bottom.  however i keep receiving an error message that says a user ID is required
[image: error message]

I went to the site and looked for my user ID, according to some of the docs the user ID should be placed after init() but there is no user ID.  I emailed support and they said the user ID was replaced by the public key.  which is what i origionally had in that space, however that's the error I receive.

This is my current code that generates the error when I attempt to send mail

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import { init } from "@emailjs/browser";

import "./contact.css";
init("wcnCiEjf9yoZnUt0e");
export default function Contact() {
  const [name, setname] = useState("");

  const [email, setemail] = useState("");
  const form = useRef();
  const [message, setmessage] = useState("");
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(e);
    console.log(form.current);

    const templateparams = {
      from_name: name + " " + email,
      to_name: "tamaraandreawilburn@gmail.com",
      feedback: message,
    };
    emailjs.send("service_e0zkrad", "template_7qrzf2e", templateparams).then(
      function (response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("FAILED...", error);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="contact-me-card row">
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 left-contact px-2 py-2">
            <span className="get-in-touch mx-4 my-5">Get in touch </span>

            <div className="py-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <lottie-player
                src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_u25cckyh.json"
                background="transparent"
                speed="1"
                style={{ width: "300px" }}
                loop
                autoplay
              ></lottie-player>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12 my-auto">
            <form
              ref={form}
              className="d-flex flex-column card-contact-right"
              onSubmit={sendEmail}
            >
              <div className="input-group my-3 d-flex flex-column">
                <label> Name </label>
                <input
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setname(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="enter your name"
                  className="input-groups"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group my-3 d-flex flex-column">
                <label>Email </label>
                <input
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setemail(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="enter your Email"
                  className="input-groups"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group my-3 d-flex flex-column">
                <label> Message </label>
                <textarea
                  value={message}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setmessage(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="enter your message"
                  className="input-groups"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group my-3 d-flex flex-column">
                <input
                  className="btn btn-success"
                  type="submit"
                  value="Send Message"
                />{" "}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated as i'm completely stuck.

Comment: Hi Tamara, I faced same problem and replacing user id with public key available in account https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/account , this link will help, also user ID has user_XXXXXXXXX format. Please try with this and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add your public_key as a 4th argument when calling `emailjs.send()`. For instance:

```
emailjs.send("service_e0zkrad", "template_7qrzf2e", templateparams, <PUBLIC_KEY>).then(
      function (response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("FAILED...", error);
      }
    );
```

This worked for me on a React app. I found it in the docs here: https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/

[image: emailjs docs]

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer. For the form value just set const form = useRef();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. This one perfectly worked for me. You should add your personal (PUBLIC_KEY), you can find it inside your email.js (**Account**) option.

```
emailjs.sendForm(
                'SERVICE_ID',
                'TEMPLATE_ID',
                form.current,
                'PUBLIC_KEY'
            )
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    alert('message sent successfully...');
                    console.log(result.text);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error.text);
                }
            );
```